# How do I solve this equation with Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, algebra, resolve

I've used `Solve`, `Reduce`, and `NSolve`, but I don't get anything

$$
\frac{w^{3w-20}-w^{w}}{w^{w}-w}=w^{w}
$$

any ideas?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 5):

Either of these seem to do the trick:

```
eqn = (w^(3 w - 20) - w^w)/(w^w - w) == w^w;

Solve[eqn, w, Reals]//N
Reduce[eqn, w, Reals]//N
NSolve[eqn, w, Reals]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given 
$$\frac{x^{3x - 20} - x^x}{x^x - x} = x^x$$
then dividing by $x^x$ leads to 
$$x^{2 x - 20} - x^x + x - 1 = 0.$$
Noticing $x=-1$ and $x=1$ are solutions then these should be expected results. For this version one could use the code

```
Solve[-1 + x - x^x + x^(-20 + 2 x) == 0 && x > -2, x, Reals]
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to be exactly 20 and 1 and -1 do not solve the original equation;

```
 myw = w /. NSolve[eqn, w, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 100];
((w^(3 w - 20) - w^w)/(w^w - w) - w^w) /. w -> 20 // N
((w^(3 w - 20) - w^w)/(w^w - w) - w^w) /. w -> myw

Out[48]= 19.

Out[49]= {0.*10^-72}
```

Also, here's a complex solution:

```
myf[x_, n_] := Exp[x Log[Abs[x]] + I (Arg[x] + 2 n Pi)];
myf3[x_, n_] := Exp[3 x Log[Abs[x]] + I (Arg[x] + 2 n Pi)];
total[x_, n_] := (myf[x, n] x^(-20) - myf[x, n])/(myf[x, n] - x) - 
   myf[x, n];

myComplex = x /. FindRoot[total[x, 0] == 0, {x, 1 + I}]
total[myComplex, 0] // N

9.91725*10^-11 - 7.81348*10^-9 I
```